# inf or Inf? nan or NaN?

Tags: matlab

It seems like both `inf` and `Inf` are exactly same in MATLAB (likewise `nan` and `NaN`, but not `Nan`). Is there any difference?

```
>> which inf
built-in (/Applications/MATLAB_R2011b.app/toolbox/matlab/elmat/inf)
>> which Inf
built-in (/Applications/MATLAB_R2011b.app/toolbox/matlab/elmat/Inf)
```

If they are the same, which one should be used in practice? For allocating arrays I have been using `x = inf(3,5)` style following `zeros` and `ones` being all small caps. For assigning single value, I use `x = Inf`. Do you think this is a consistent use?

Comment: If I have read it correctly, your use of `Inf` and `inf` indeed appears to be consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the conventions that MATLAB appears to use:

For Not-a-Number: Always use `NaN` (Except in combinations such as `isnan()`

For Infinite: Use `inf` for the function and use `Inf` for the value (and `INFs` for multiples, but this is not a command of course). Note that this is a bit tricky as it means that the evaluation of `inf` gives `Inf`.

Deduced from:

`help Inf`: inf(N) is an N-by-N matrix of INFs.

`help nan`: NaN(N) is an N-by-N matrix of NaNs.

`help isnan`:  For example, isnan([pi NaN Inf -Inf]) is [0 1 0 0].

Answer (score 11):

Most idiomatically consistent would be `nan` and `inf` but MATLAB offers you the alternative way of capitalizing `NaN` and `Inf`, the way you will find it everywhere else, like in printouts, for example. Note that MATLAB *is* case sensitive. Nobody will use `Nan` or `InF`, so MATLAB does not provide these "aliases".

**EDIT:**
For use in a data vector, as in `[3.7, 1.2, NaN, 3.1]`, I consistently find myself using `NaN` as well, but the following experiment suggests *very strongly* that this use is **not** intimate with MATLAB's internal workings. Create a function `n = NaN()` returning 4 and save it as `NaN.m` in your current folder. Defining the vector like above will result in `[3.7, 1.2, 4.0, 3.1]` showing that *MATLAB does not understand* `NaN` *as a constant*, and will look up a function, which, in accordance with MATLAB idioms, should be spelled all lowercase.

Now let's quickly delete `NaN.m` before we forget, and keep using `NaN` in data columns.

Comment: But MATLAB always shows values as `Inf` and `NaN`, so when assigning a single value, using `Inf` instead of `inf` (which is supposedly a function that assigns arrays of `Inf`'s) makes sense as @Dennis suggests.

Comment: @Memming, see my edit, my initial answer was on the use as in `nan(3)`. *Printout* is one thing, but there is no constant `NaN` in the MATLAB *language*. Turns out it's always parsed as a function.

Comment: (Re: on your edits) True. If you try `nan.m`, it does exactly the same thing as well. Therefore neither is a constant or reserved keyword (though MATLAB complains for both that the function is a MATLAB builtin). My question was simply about which is a better convention, and I think it is more cultural in this case. No need to start a flame war over this. :)

Comment: So your point is that since it is a function, like all other MATLAB builtin functions, it should be called in lower case, right? But, conceptually, I think of NaN as a constant, which is probably why MATLAB prints it out as `NaN`.